# Where do Crash Reports on Android go in Developer console

Tags: android, crash-reports

I have been working on an android project and published it to the market. I then installed the app on my device via the play store and upon doing something I found a possible way to crash the app.

When the app force closed it asked me if I wanted to send a report which I did so I could see what it looks like in the developer console.

I added some text about what I did to cause the app to force close and could then view what the crash report looked like and it conained various information like device make and model etc. I submitted and I logged in to my developer account but could not see any of the information within the crash report other than the message I put inside explaining what I did.

Where does the rest of the information go as unless someone actually says what phone or android version they are running in the message I don't what I need to replicate the issue.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK, you cannot view the device etc. in the developer console. You can only view the user message (if provided) or the stack trace. Beyond that there is no more information as far as I know.

However, you can get much more information by integrating [ACRA](http://code.google.com/p/acra) into your application. This will give you a huge amount of information about the crash, including memory statistics, the device, the android version it is running etc.

**EDIT**

It would seem that the device at least is displayed in the new Developer Console, but the information still isn't even close to what ACRA provides.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me to use ACRA instead in the apps. Has been put off for too long. The google docs/drive spreadsheet option is such a great feature too.

Answer (score 2):

With the standard report included it depends a bit on android(?) or play store app version what details you get in your reports it seems. In the publisher/developer console (example from the new developer console version):

[image: Crash report from Developer Console]

Comment: Ah, yea I do get that screen but for some reason the device is always ``OTHER``, my crash report I did for my app was on a unlocked/unbranded samsung galaxy s3 running 4.1 jelly bean in the market it says its other for some reason. Thanks for your help though

Comment: You can also filter error reports based on models in the previous screen there.